# Laptop and tablet restrictions within US air travel

Tags: air-travel, usa, electronic-items

I will be flying to Boston, MA from Cincinnati, OH for a 6 month internship. I want to carry two laptops(a mac and a windows) along with an iPad in the cabin baggage. While the mac is my primary computer, I will require the windows laptop to finish my school thesis work. I had purchased both the laptops in the US, and I have the bill for both of them.

Would I face any trouble in either airport due to the two laptops and the tablet? I searched online but could not find a rule, per se, for domestic travel within the US.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

As long as your cabin baggage meets the size and weight requirements for the airline, they don't care what you put in it (except airport security will check for dangerous goods). There are no customs procedures for domestic flights.

Comment: Do, however, be prepared to remove *both* laptops from your bag as you pass through airport security. So don't pack them at the bottom of your carry on or something similarly stupid.

Comment: I have personally often traveled with two laptops. Nobody cares as long as you keep within the weight and size limits - why should they? It is perfectly legal to travel with *ten* laptops...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you'll be fine, even in 2021.

The only trouble you'll face is what you *may* or *may not* perceive as an inconvenience when having to remove and repack the devices while going through airport security (TSA). Depending on the person, there might be added anxiety from the amount of time you take to unpack and repack everything if there's an impatient, crowded line of people behind you but that's a personal topic.
That is to say, you'll be fine and should be able to bring them with you with limitations primarily coming from your airline and particular ticket flight details (such as carry on size limits or fees associated with multiple carry-ons, whereas a laptop bag can sometimes be considered a personal item if you're not carry a purse/satchel or other personal bag) In addition to both types of electronics require being removed from any bag and placed separately in the bins that you send through X-ray, you might on occasion run into someone who's unfamiliar with a device who might ask you to turn it on if they're really suspicious but otherwise you're good in terms of security. It's mostly the airliner and how you plan to pack all the devices that would be more cause of concerns of extra fees.

In terms of bringing them on board with you, even though the OP already clarified needing both laptops, it's worth noting that even with the [lithium battery restrictions](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-49/subtitle-B/chapter-I/subchapter-C/part-175/subpart-A/section-175.10) that were imposed, you can pack a laptop inside of luggage that you plan to check-in. Albeit bringing attention to this, it's also worth noting however, that the [FAA](https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/more_info/?hazmat=20) does say,

> Devices containing lithium metal or lithium ion batteries (laptops,
> smartphones, tablets, etc.) should be carried in carry-on baggage when
> possible.

The emphasis here being "when possible." This all applies to standard boarding passengers while those with [TSA PreCheck](https://www.tsa.gov/precheck) have a more [lenient policy](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/travel-tips/travel-checklist) by comparison when it comes to carry-on laptops and tablets (noting that the last section of the link for lenient policy has a brief instructional for standard screening lane).